# Update dynamoDb item in java

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to update dynamoDB by using ***put*** operation, if I provide providing same partition key and sort key with updated values.
So it will overwrite the original values or will throw an exception?

Comment: That is explained in the very first sentence of the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html "*Creates a new item, or replaces an old item with a new item"*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DynamoDB Java API Version 2 to update an item by using the **DynamoDbClient** object's **updateItem** method. Here is the full example:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/UpdateItem.java